# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '‍' in 'field list'

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mariadb, mysql-command-line-client

I get this annoying error when I try to insert data from db1 to db2 in MaridaDB 10 using mysql CLI. This is while all the columns exist.

```sql
INSERT INTO db2.thread (threadid, title, postuserid, dateline, views)
SELECT  `nid`, `title`, `uid`, ‍‍`created`,
`comment`   from db1.node  where type = 'forum'  and status = 1;
```

When I execute the same query in PHPMyAdmin, I get:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'â€

I tried different syntax like 'like' etc. with no avail. Appreciate your hints

Comment: Start by double checking that your column names match what you're typing in the query. Also, check that there are no invisible garbage characters in the query.

Comment: I double-checked. All the columns exist on both databases.

Comment: I execute it from mysql CLI. How should I check for 'garbage characters'? Data are in utf8, so there may be some weird characters.

Comment: If it's an invisible garbage character, it's not in the data, it's in the query. Try retyping the query from scratch instead of cut'n'pasting it.

Comment: ok, I rewritten the query AND added bactick (`) for type column. It solved the problem. Thanks Joachim. I accept if you add the answer.

Comment: Check your triggers if you have any. Maybe there is a typo in a column name which leeds also to this error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like there are invisible garbage characters in your query.

Try retyping the query (don't copy and paste or you'll most likely include the garbage character) and it should work.

Comment: I think the main problem was missing bacticks (``) from the type column. Please mention this.

Comment: @qliq I'm having no trouble with the same query without backticks around "type", if you can verify that that is the problem, it's better if you write an answer explaining it since I can't repeat it nor explain why that would be a problem on your MySQL version :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've typed it like this:

```
INSERT INTO Details (Name, Age) VALUES (Anamika, 24);
```

Try changing it to:

```
INSERT INTO Details (Name, Age) VALUES ('Anamika',24);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `USER` to show the current user, I got the same error as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT USER;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'USER' in 'field list'
```

So instead, I ran `USER()`, then I could show the current user as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT USER();
+----------------+
| USER()         |
+----------------+
| john@localhost |
+----------------+
```